# How to get Eclipse running on El Capitan?

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I have a fresh install of El Capitan.  I have installed Java 8 from java.com.  I have downloaded eclipse.  When I go to run it, I get the error message:

To open "Eclipse-inst" you need to install the legacy Java SE 6 runtime

There has to be another way other then installing an ancient version of Java on this machine to get the latested Eclipse. All I am seeking to do is some Django development with PyDev.

Comment: From java.com? Did you install the JRE or the JDK?

Comment: This is a known issue. See: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/157641/yosemite-keeps-asking-to-install-java-runtime-while-its-installed

Answer (score 1):

Install [Java 6](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) from Apple. It includes propietary APIs made by apple. Java 6 should install fine along with your current java version.

Comment: Eclipse might require Apple's Java release for better compatability with OS X.